# TRIM on hdd windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, trim

I recently bought a ssd and I wanted to check for TRIM support. Upon running the command `fsutil behavior query DisableDeleteNotify` in cmd it resulted in 0 (trim is enabled). However, I ran this command on my windows 7 installation with a HDD, and it resulted in 0 also. Why is this? It is obviously a hdd. Will trim on a hdd affect its performance/lifespan?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That command is returning if the OS has TRIM support enabled or not.

It's not tied to a specific drive, and you don't necessarily even need an SSD in the system (at all) for it to report 0.

Answer (score 4):

The setting is stored by Windows, but it won't actually be used unless Windows has an SSD to work with. Since TRIM is an SSD feature, that setting has zero effect on hard drives.

Answer (score 1):

to clear your doubts, hdds currently do not support trim. future hdds may support trim to improve data resillency. that is, trim will tell the hdd about useless sectors and the hdd can copy data to them or if a sector fails and there are no reserved sectors, it may be able to shrink its size